# Rendered animation has black frames at start and end

Tags: rendering, animation

I saved an animation as a set of images. It is 2800 frames, and the first 135 and the last 563 are just black. When I play the animation by going into camera view and clicking play in the Timeline, it plays fine, but when it renders, it cuts out a bunch of intermediate frames and fills in the beginning and end with black frames.

There is no Time Remapping, and it is set to No Sync. I had decided to change the frame rate from 25 to 30, so I increased the number of frames, scaled the keyframes on the Dope Sheet, and changed the Render > Dimensions > Frame Rate field to 30. So, maybe that is a reason, but I can't see why. What is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a condensed version of your file

Comment: @Leander I added a BlendExchange

Comment: Wondering about the image sequence (that starts at frame 136) in the VSE and having sequencer post processing enabled is your issue.  (It renders my own images from my temp folder lol)

Comment: @batFINGER Yep, that worked. If you put it as an answer, i'd like to upvote and accept it. Thanks :)